# Calling Java class from JSP button onclick

Tags: java, html, jsp

I am trying to to call a Java class when a button gets clicked from JSP. inside my JSP file I have the following:

```
<%
  Object name = session.getAttribute("name");
  Object ext = session.getAttribute("ext");
  DBOps ops = new DBOps();
  ReturnGetDisplayInfo GDI = ops.getDisplayInfo(ext); 
%>
```

I have a method in DBOps that will delete a certain field so I added a button to teh table that displays the information and now I am trying to call the delete method when the button is clicked. so I tried doing the following but it did not work.

```
<td><button onclick=<% ops.delete(ext); %>>Delete</button></td>
```

I was looking at some examples that utilize javascript but it uses defiend functions in teh script rather than calling the Java class.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that directly. You need a roundtrip to the server.

The best option for that is [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29):

- make a servlet that handles performs the delete request when a certain url is invoked
- use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) (or native XmlHttpRequest) to invoke that url

([DWR - direct web remoting](http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/index.html) is also an option, which is implemented using AJAX)

Comment: I am looking at DWR to help do this, can you post a simple example please. I do not have any servlets and I am not sure how to add one in my case. all I have is JSP files and I am calling Java classes and using them just fine using the <% %> tag. its just the button click that I am struggling with

Answer (score 0):

One example of my code, in javascript and ajax, if it can help you:

On my jsp i have a onClick"changeTimeZone(org)"

Javascript:

```
function changeTimeZone(org)
{
    //Prepare a new ajaxRequest.
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        //state 4 is response ready.
        //Status 200 is page found.
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {

        //fill the timezone field with the reponse of my servlet.
        document.getElementById('timeZoneText').value = xmlhttp.responseText;

    }
  };

  //send an ajax request.
  //Go to my servlet
  xmlhttp.open('GET','mainServlet?command=ajax.ChangeTimeZone&Org=' + org.value, true);
  xmlhttp.send();

}
```

Comment: You are calling XMLHttpRequest in your javascript which is ok, but this does not work for calling a different class the script does not even see my classes